# Searching for AD Group Membership

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, active-directory-group

I am building a script to find AD Users that have not logged in X number of days and do not belong to a specific security group. I have 2 users in the OU, one of which is in the DoNotDisable security group (pileum) and one which is not (bubba).

```
$DC = Get-ADDomainController
$OUs = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -eq "test"'
$accounts = $null
$canNotDisable = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity DoNotDisable -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$TimeStamp = get-date -format D
$description = "Disabled on " + $TimeStamp

foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    # Search for User Accounts inactive for XX Days and Disable if not in DoNotDisable Security Group
    $accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $OU -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]90d) -UsersOnly
        foreach($account in $accounts){
        If ($canNotDisable -contains $account){
        Write-Host "$account can not be disabled"
        } Else {
        Write-Host "$account can be disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

If I look at the $canNotDisable variable it is pulling the correct user in the DoNotDisable group.

[image]

However when I run the full script it returns both the user in the group and the user not in the group.

[image]

I would be extremely grateful if someone can help me figure out what I'm missing. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement in inner foreach loop to match against the IDs, not the whole object.

Since `$canNotDisable` is a list of strings, you will need to get the name out of the `$Account` variable to see if that exists (not the resulting object).

```
foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    # Search for User Accounts inactive for XX Days and Disable if not in DoNotDisable Security Group
    $accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $OU -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]90d) -UsersOnly
        foreach($account in $accounts){
        If ($canNotDisable -contains $account.Name){
        Write-Host "$account can not be disabled"
        } Else {
        Write-Host "$account can be disabled"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I felt like I was 99% there and really appreciate you getting me to the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that the objects returned by Get-ADGroupMember are not of the same type as those returned by Get-ADUser. They both represent AD Users but the objects are not equivalent and, perhaps surprisingly, comparison has not been made to work correctly for objects of these types.

If this is the issue, I'd expect first getting a list of ObjectGUIDs from the $canNotDisable list (e.g., $canNotDisableGuids = $canNotDisable | %{$_.ObjectGuid}) and then checking to see if each user's ObjectGUID is in the list, might actually work. It appears the same ObjectGUIDs are in both objects.